# A foreign key constraint fails on laravel 5 framework

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working on laravel 5 framework.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database_name`.`students`, CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`stu_id`) REFERENCES `admission_details` (`ad_id`))

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Please show related code, migrations, and relationships if you use any.

Comment: stu_id does not have a matching ad_id in admission_details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query in phpmyadmin

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `admission_details`(`ad_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Hope it's help you